# In C, will !0 always return 1?

Tags: c, integer, zero

This program anecdotally shows that the integer value of `! 0` is `1`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  printf( "%d\n", ! 0 );
  return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc --version && gcc -g ./main.c && ./a.out
gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

1
$
```

Is this guaranteed by any standard, or could `! 0` ever evaluate to any other nonzero integer value?

Comment: The ISO C standard should explain this very explicitly.  Did you look there?

Comment: @NateEldredge - indeed it is in there, as John's answer revealed. Frankly, I've always been intimidated to try look up information that way - those standard documents have always seemed so large and overwhelming; I'm frankly amazed that people can find information in there as quickly as they seem able to.

Comment: It comes with practice. Don't be scared, just read and try and understand what you can. With more exposure that will become more familiar.

Comment: @StoneThrow: A reasonable compromise is https://cppreference.com, which despite the name covers C as well as C++.  It follows the standards pretty closely but is a bit more user friendly.  It's organized like the standards, so I found [the relevant page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical) under "C reference -> Expressions -> Operators:logical" and got the answer: "Its value is 1 if expression evaluates to a value that compares equal to zero."

Comment: @StoneThrow: They’re like any other reference - start with the ToC and index, and you can find what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is guaranteed to evaluate to `1`.

> **6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators**
> ...
> 5     The result of the logical negation operator `!` is 0 if the value of its operand compares
> unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type `int`.
> The expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>